# Solving $y'=y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

(Here solution means any function from an interval of $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies (1). No distributions or "weak solutions" or whatever allowed.)

To find all once-differentiable functions from any interval of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ of $$y'=y^2\ \ \ \ (1)$$

Let's first assume $y\neq 0$. Then we can divide both sides of $(1)$ and integrate them wrt t, obtaining $$-\frac{1}{y} = t+C,\ \ \ C\in \mathbb{R}\ \ \ $$

This implies that $t\neq -C$ in the case $y\neq 0$, and the solutions in that case are $$y=-\frac{1}{t+C},\ \ \ (2)$$

as long as we are in an interval that doesn't contain $-C$, else there's no solution in that case.

Now for dealing with the case where $y=0$ somewhere. Say $y(t_0)=0$. It is clear that $y(t)=0$ is a solution on any interval. Now, since $(1)$ if of the form $y' = f(t,y)$ where $f$ is continuous wrt $t$ and, after picking a bounded interval, uniformly lipschitz wrt $y$, Picard-Lindelöf's theorem gives that the only solution to (1) that satisfies $y(t_0)=0$ on a given interval that contains $t_0$ is $y(t)=0$. Therefore, letting the picked bounded interval $\to \mathbb{R}$ we get that $y(t)=0$ everywhere is the only solution in this case.

So the full set of solutions are $(2)$ on intervals that don't contain $-C$ and $y(t)=0$ on any interval. Is this correct and fully rigorous?

Also, why does wolfram alpha not include the $y(t)=0$ solution?

Comment: This looks correct and rigorous to me. However, saying "$y\neq 0$" is misleading, as you are really saying "$y(t)\neq 0$ for all $t$ in the interval of interest."

Comment: Indeed that's what i meant, i see that it can be ambiguous. I found a small mistake: Picard-Lindelöf, as stated in wikipedia doesn't let you choose the bounded interval, instead it asserts there's a closed $\varepsilon$-ball centered of $t_0$ where the solution is unique. Thankfully, since the ball is closed i think we can just keep applying it at the end points (possibly countably many times? actually might not work since at limit ordinals you might have a open interval).

Comment: Well, after applying countably many times (say from the right for simplicity), you get that you have $y(t)=0$ for all t in some interval $[a, b)$. If $b$ is infinity done. Else any open ball centered at $b$ contains elements from that interval so $y(t)=0$ there too so we should be able to finish by transfinite induction.

Comment: This is a bit of a problem depending on what „version“ of Picard-Lindelöf you use. For example, if you use Theorem 1.1.5 from the notes here: https://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?id=ve_vo_det&key2=4050&semId=41, then you don’t have to deal with the $\delta$-subtleties.